# How can I change a path automatically for calling firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'me making my project base on firebase environment.
And for sending GET and DELETE call not only POST call. I'd registered my function with method .onRequest (because .onCall only supports POST call, I've checked this in document)

And now I wanted to call my function from frontend.

So I fetched call with this.

```
fetch(API_ROOT+"/api/sentences", {
  method: "GET"
})
```

And so I had to use my condition for not relying on the environment, dev or dist.

```
let API_ROOT = ""
if (location.hostname == "127.0.0.1" || location.hostname == "localhost") {
  console.log("This is local emulator environment")
  functions.useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001")
  API_ROOT = "http://localhost:5001/[my-project-id]/us-central1"
}else{
  API_ROOT = "https://us-central1-[my-project-id].cloudfunctions.net" 
}
```

But should I use this? Or is there any way similar to the .httpsCallable method with .onCall registering.

Because that one doesn't need a full path for calling, like below.

```
functions
  .httpsCallable("api/sentences")()
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client SDK for [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) is only intended to work with functions that you declare using `onCall` (I suggest reviewing that documentation again).  It's almost certainly not expected to work with normal HTTP triggers declared with `onRequest`.  Callable functions have their own very specific [protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) and do not allow you to change the name or path URI of the function.

If you have an HTTP trigger, skip the Firebase client library and just use a regular HTTP client like you would with any other HTTP API.

Comment: I've resolved my problem which through suited in my situation
And it was the same solution with my other question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810640/how-can-i-using-hosting-rewirtes-to-connect-between-firebase-hosting-and-cloud-f